# Upload Pictures from Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, upload, chatter-feed, files, chatter-file

How to make sure user uploads two or more pictures(before picture,after picture) before closing the status of service request.

So, I have enabled feed tracking on service request custom object and provided access to files from Salesforce1 and now when users tries to  uploads pictures using files then picture is added as chatter feed and also added to files related list.

But how to validate the user to make sure he/she uploads two pictures before moving the status of service request to Closed.

Comment: You could write a trigger on your service request object and query the `ContentDocument` records using its `parentId` field matched with service request record id.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. Write trigger on `ContentDocumentLink` object, it will actually fire when you are trying upload the file.
2. In `ContentDocumentLink` object there is a field called `LinkedEntityId` which actually stores the related object id.
3. Now from related object id you can query in the object and check the status of service request to Closed or not.
4. Based on the you can also call `adderror` if you want show any kind of error to the user.

Comment: I don't think a trigger on `ContentDocumentLink` can possibly help here.